# Change Google Spreadsheet tab/sheet color using script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to use Google Scripts from within a Google Spreadsheet to change the tab color for the sheet (when you right-click a tab at the bottom, there's an option to Change Color, and there's a thin colored line under the name of the sheet/tab).

Can't find anything in the Google Spreadsheet Scripts documentation.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: there's already [a request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4193) for this in the Issue Tracker if you want to star it

Comment: Has been added. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setTabColor(String)

Answer (score 15):

FYI, Google have listened to the issue mentioned previously by Cyrus Loree and Bryan P and have now added the ability to colour the sheet tab using apps script.

See here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#settabcolorcolor

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: sheet.setTabColor("ff0000");